# C++, OLE, Excel Automation: EAccessviolation at 00000800

Tags: c++, excel, exception, ole

I am writing an background service application that has to automatically read data from Excel 2003 files. But no matter what I try, the method OlePropertyGet() always results in an EAccessViolation error while trying to read from address "00000800".

The error always occurs at the last line of this code snippet, and seems independent of what parameter the method receives:

```
Variant excel, workbooks;

try
{
    excel = GetActiveOleObject("Excel.Application");
}
catch(...)
{
    excel = CreateOleObject("Excel.Application");
}

workbooks = excel.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks");
```

I've done some extensive google search on this, but found nothing that's even remotely helpful, only [this](http://topic.csdn.net/t/20040316/18/2850019.html) forum thread where someone has the same issue, but doesn't give any information about the cause or solution (it's somewhat funny that at one point the author mentions he knows the cause, but doesn't say what it is!).

I'm open to any ideas as to what is causing this and how to solve this problem, but also alternative approaches to Excel OLE automation.

Comment: If your application is trying to read to 0x800 address, this doesn't look too good.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is its a null pointer issue..

It looks like neither `GetActiveOleObject()` nor `CreateOleObject()` worked.

Try checkign the validity of 'excel'  before calling `OlePropertyGet`.

And I guess you should make sure you have Excel installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio Tools for Office (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx).

Or you can use ATL support to instantiate the object model provided by office.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may not be able to resolve "Excel.Application" successfully, leading to a null pointer. It uses a registry lookup with that string to identify Excel. It sounds like you're missing that registry entry.

Answer (score 0):

I use such code to determine validity of created objects(in C++ Builder):

```
Varaint excel = GetActiveOleObject("Excel.Application");
TAutoDriver<IDispatch> dispatcher;
dispatcher.Bind(excel, false);

if (dispatcher.IsBound())
{
    Variant workbooks = excel.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks");   
}
```